# Bity IPhone App gone

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-recovery, private-key-import

I had a couple of bitcoins in a iPhone “Bity” app wallet.  I hadn’t accessed that wallet in a few years. After hearing the recent bitcoin value, I decided to get into my wallet to see how many bitcoins I have. Well the Bity app is gone and so is my private key.  I can only “watch” my bitcoins with my public key.  Is it possible to import a private key that’s attached to those bitcoins?

Comment: Do you have a backup of that wallet, on iCloud maybe or somewhere else or have you written down somewhere a bunch of words (serves as a seed)?

Comment: Thanks for your help. No. So far I’ve been turning my house upside down.